# Issues With Sending Large Data Over Websockets With Chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, websocket

I have been attempting to write a java HTTP server from scratch for my chat program that sends data over websockets and everything has been going well until I started trying to send large images with my program using google chrome. I discovered that when chrome is sending multiple frames of data to my server, it never sends the proper length of the data. The first frame is always fine, but all frames after the initial one send a number that is significantly smaller than the data that the frame contains. For example, it will send a frame saying that it contains 123 bytes of data, when it is really sending over 100 kilobytes. I have tested other browsers like firefox and safari (on my phone) and they don't seem to split up large data into frames like chrome does, so they don't have the same issue. Here are some screenshots of my results:
Initial frame:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Jn6W.png)

Following frames (This is where it fails):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dg3SI.png)

And here is my server side code that gets the data from an input stream and writes it to a file:

```
byte[] headerdata = new byte[12];
input.read(headerdata, 0, 2);
int frame = (headerdata[0] & 0b10000000) & 0xFF;
long length = (headerdata[1] & 0b01111111) & 0xFF;
System.out.format("Before: %d, Frame: %d%n", length, frame);
if(length == 127){
    input.read(headerdata, 0, 12);
    length = ((long)(headerdata[0] << 56) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFL | (long)(headerdata[1] << 48) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFL | (long)(headerdata[2] << 40) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFL | (long)(headerdata[3] << 32) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFL | (headerdata[4] << 24) & 0xFFFFFFFFL | (headerdata[5] << 16) & 0xFFFFFFL | (headerdata[6] << 8) & 0xFFFFL | headerdata[7] & 0xFFL)
} else if(length == 126){
    input.read(headerdata, 6, 6);
    length = ((headerdata[6] << 8) & 0xFFFF | headerdata[7] & 0xFF);
}else{
    input.read(headerdata, 8, 4);
}
System.out.println("After: " + length);

int count;
int total = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];
boolean done = false;
while(done == false){
    count = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    //System.out.println(count);
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        buffer[i] = (byte)(buffer[i] ^ headerdata[(total & 3) + 8]);
        total++;
    }
    fileoutput.write(buffer, 0, count);
    System.out.format("Count: %d Left: %d%n", count, (length - total));
    if(total >= length){
        done = true;
    }
}

if(frame == 128) break;
```

Any explanation as to why I might be failing to read the length of following frames would be greatly appreciated (I have a few suspicions of my own as well). Thank you for your time and efforts.

Comment: You keep assuming that `read()` fills the buffer, without checking for end of stream or a short read. Use `DataInputStream.readFully()`: in fact some of these reads could be done with `readInt()` and friends.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found out that the buffer ends up overflowing, resulting in data being misread or lost, which is why I was getting the wrong length values from the frames. I fixed it by adding an if statement that checks to see if the number of bytes read are approaching the length value of that frame, and then only read what is left instead of the full buffer size to stop it from overflowing. Here is the code with the modification:

```
byte[] headerdata = new byte[12];
                input.read(headerdata, 0, 2);
                int frame = (headerdata[0] & 0b10000000) & 0xFF;
                long length = (headerdata[1] & 0b01111111) & 0xFF;
                System.out.format("Before: %d, Frame: %d%n", length, frame);
                if(length == 127){
                    input.read(headerdata, 0, 12);
                    length = ((long)(headerdata[0] << 56) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFL | (long)(headerdata[1] << 48) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFL | (long)(headerdata[2] << 40) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFL | (long)(headerdata[3] << 32) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFL | (headerdata[4] << 24) & 0xFFFFFFFFL | (headerdata[5] << 16) & 0xFFFFFFL | (headerdata[6] << 8) & 0xFFFFL | headerdata[7] & 0xFFL);
                }else if(length == 126){
                    input.read(headerdata, 6, 6);
                    length = ((headerdata[6] << 8) & 0xFFFF | headerdata[7] & 0xFF);
                }else{
                    input.read(headerdata, 8, 4);
                }
                System.out.println("After: " + length);

                int count;
                int total = 0;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];
                boolean done = false;
                while(done == false){
                    if(length - total > buffer.length) count = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                    else count = input.read(buffer, 0, (int) (length - total));
                    //System.out.println(count);
                    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
                        buffer[i] = (byte)(buffer[i] ^ headerdata[(total & 3) + 8]);
                        total++;
                    }
                    fileoutput.write(buffer, 0, count);
                    //System.out.format("Count: %d Left: %d%n", count, (length - total));
                    if(total >= length){
                        done = true;
                    }
                }

                if(frame == 128) break;
```

I also did some research on different ways to read byte streams from a socket and found that it would also be possible to use `DataInputStream.readFully()`.

Comment: You are *still* assuming that reads fill the buffer and *still* ignoring end-of-stream and short reads. You need to fix this.

Comment: I am confused. The code I shared continues to read until it reads the exact number of bytes from the length value sent in the frame. My issue was from over reading, which resulted in skipping the header of the next frame. I cannot check for the end of the stream since it gets stuck waiting, which I assume is because the websocket stays open after sending the data, and I do not understand what you mean by short reads.